# django for professionals book

Tags: django, docker

I am currently on page 241 of the "Django for professionals" book. Adding command  gunicorn config.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 to docker-compose-prod.yml made it impossible to rebuild docker image with docker-compose up -d --build command,  error is  yaml.scanner.ScannerError appears : mapping values are not allowed here in ". \ docker-compose.yml", line 7, column 12. Is this a bug of the author of the book?

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  command: gunicorn config.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=ldBHq0YGYxBzaMJnLVOiNG7hruE8WKzGG2zGpYxoTNmphB0mdBo"

  db:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
     - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: YAML format is whitespace-sensitive (same as python). Your `command: gunicorn config.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000` in under-indented (it should align with the previous line).

Second: you cannot have two `command` entries - only one can be used at a time. So if you want to use `gunicorn` - leave only that entry.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn config.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ...
```